# Laravel 5.2 run in localhost without using php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Okay, so I created a Laravel 5.2 app (mylaravel). I am currently working in Ubuntu 14.04 with XAMPP for Linux 5.6.15. The app works whenever I run it using `php artisan serve` (afterwards it works by visiting `http://localhost:8000` <-shows my login page). I can login/logout, etc. Without running the `artisan serve` first, visiting `http://localhost/mylaravel` will render my login page BUT upon trying to login it says "The localhost page isn’t working" with error code 500. What I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What's likely happening is that laravel is assuming your root is at `localhost/` but in reality it's at `localhost/mylaravel`. I'm not sure laravel even supports this, at any case, look into creating a virtual host for your site so you can access it as e.g. `http://virtual.host.com/`

Comment: You do not need xampp if you're using `artisan serve`.  the 500 is likely a hidden error message

Answer (score 1):

Using your xampp shell and changed to your project directory, try

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t public
```

then you should be able to access your project by using localhost:8888 in a browser

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that in your XAMPP manager you have MySQL and Apache both turned on.

Second, make sure that all your databases, tables and so on are in your MySQL XAMPP instance. You can check this by using PHPMyAdmin which comes with your XAMPP install: `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

If all is good and you're still getting a 500 error, check your apache logs within your XAMPP instance.